# How can I get the coefficient of variation in a group by with Python + Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I'm trying to analyze some data in a homework of a course I'm doing. For that, I want to have the coefficient of variation of some values, but I don't know how to do it. Already searched on the internet and didn't find an easy way.

Just for sake of information:

Coefficient of variation = standard deviation / mean

I can have both standard deviation and mean while grouping data by day using this code:

```
-- the following code gives standard deviation by day
display(full_data.groupby(['DAY'])['STEPS', 'CALORIES'].std())

-- the following code gives mean by day
display(full_data.groupby(['DAY'])['STEPS', 'CALORIES'].mean())
```

I wanted to do the same with a "pvariation()" method, but there isn't one, or at least I didn't found it anywhere.
Maybe I can do it in another way, like a lambda or something. Can someone help me doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use: full_data.groupby(['DAY'])['STEPS', 'CALORIES'].std()/full_data.groupby(['DAY'])['STEPS', 'CALORIES'].mean() ?

Comment: @idnavid nice! It works just fine! Exactly what I needed. I didn't knew I could do that. I'm new to Python, sorry. Thanks anyway! Can you write an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Actually, it's called [_coefficient of variation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation), not variance and there is [`scipy.stats.variation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.variation.html).

Comment: @PaulPanzer yes, you're right. I've write it in a wrong way. I'll correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used @idnavid's comment as the answer, but he didn't created an official answer, so I'm creating it.

I've used the following formula:

```
full_data.groupby(['DAY'])['STEPS', 'CALORIES'].std() / full_data.groupby(['DAY'])['STEPS', 'CALORIES'].mean()
```